# Why does pandas `date_range` rounds up to the next month?

Tags: python, pandas, date-range

When using `pandas.date_range` with start date, frequency, and periods the date range rounds up when using the start date as the last day of a month.

It seems like a silent edge case bug. If it's not a bug, any idea why it does that?

For example

```py
import pandas as pd

start_date = pd.Timestamp(2023, 5, 31)
date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, freq="MS", periods=6)
```

results in

```py
DatetimeIndex(['2023-06-01', '2023-07-01', '2023-08-01', '2023-09-01',
               '2023-10-01', '2023-11-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
```

From the documentation, I'd expect it to start in May and end in October:

```py
DatetimeIndex(['2023-05-01', '2023-06-01', '2023-07-01', '2023-08-01', '2023-09-01',
               '2023-10-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
```

I thought it had to do with the `inclusive` argument but that's not the reason either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.date_range` is to generate a range of date between `start` and `end`. `2023-05-01` is less than start date `2023-05-31`, it will never reach it. To do what you want, you can replace the day of `pd.Timestamp` by 1.

```py
start_date = pd.Timestamp(2023, 5, 31)
date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date.replace(day=1), freq="MS", periods=6)
```

```
print(date_range)

DatetimeIndex(['2023-05-01', '2023-06-01', '2023-07-01', '2023-08-01',
               '2023-09-01', '2023-10-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation and going the extra step to show what it should be

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) reads

> *"such that they all satisfy start <[=] x <[=] end"*

Therefore, as the date provided is `pd.Timestamp(2023, 5, 31)`, the first `"MS"` (start-of-month) date that satisfies `start <= x` is the following month.